# How can I create the first IAM role to assume with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I'm trying to set up AWS with Terraform and confused about [aws_iam_role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html).

So to create a first role(let say poweruser), `aws_iam_role` requires `assume_role_policy`, which is a role arn to assume. (But there is no poweruser role with poweruser policy yet.)

It feels like I'm in chicken and egg situation - to create a role, I need another role to assume, but can't create since I don't have a role to assume yet.

How can I do this with Terraform? Am I misunderstood something? or Do I need to do some initial role/user set up by manual first?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time running your Terraform script, I suggest Adding a user in the console with **Programmatic Access**, attach an AWS Managed Policy (like AdministratorAccess) and make sure to save `Access key ID` and `Secret access key`.

Then, in your HOME directory `cd ~`, create a folder `.aws`

Inside .aws directory create a file named credentials.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = paste
aws_secret_access_key = paste
```

In your terraform file:

```
provider "aws" {
    profile = "default" #pertains to the default profile included in credentials file
    region = "us-east-2"
    version = "~> 2.26.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So you mean I need a manual step for Terraform access, right?

Comment: Tp set up Terraform on your machine, yes you need the manual step to be able perform terraform commands like `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`. When you are able to perform terraform commands, that's when you can proceed with creating your resources such as roles, policies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the first IAM user `manually` to get an `access key` and `secret_key` for Terraform.

More precisely saying, for example, you've just made an aws account and there are no IAM users made which means there is no access key and secret key existed at all. However, Terraform must need `access key` and `secret_key` to be performed.

```
# AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-northeast-1"
  access_key = "AIKAWP3TMGZNG34RUWRS"
  secret_key = "RNA6yaOwlOw4AEuFaBH2qJzSh/aE1zhFL5cbvgbb"
}
```

So you must make an IAM user `manually` for `only the first IAM user` to get `access key` and `secret_key` to perform Terraform. After making the first IAM user and give the `access key` and `secret_key` to Terraform, you are able to make other IAM users with Terraform without manual ways.